# Doxygen Out of Line Documenting for C++ Class Operators

Tags: c++, doxygen

If I have a class in a file I can't change, but I need to document in doxygen, what is the best way to do it? I know it would be best to document in the actual .h or .cpp file, but in this specific instance, that is not possible.

I have figured out how to document some members, but I cannot document operators in a reliable way. Let me provide an example. Here is an example class with a member that has caused problems and one that worked fine:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int Bar();
    bool operator!() const;
};
```

In some other file that doxygen looks through, I have put the following:

```
/// @fn Foo::Bar
/// @brief Some info about the constructor
/// @return Some stuff about what bar returns
```

The documentation for the constructor works, but this doesn't:

```
/// @fn Foo::operator!
/// @brief Some info about the operator
/// @return Some stuff about what the operator! returns
```

neither does:

```
/// @fn operator!
/// @memberof Foo
/// @brief Some info about the operator
/// @return Some stuff about what the operator! returns
```

I have also tried escaping various parts with a % and . So it looked like "/// @fn %operator!", "/// @fn operator%!" or "/// @fn operator!" but nothing likes this has helped.

The Info about the operator never shows up. A few times I tried putting a unique value into the operator doxygen comments and grepping for it in the doxygen output and I came up empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at your doxygen output, there should be a warning

```
/path/to/Documentation: warning: no matching class member found for
  Foo::operator!()
Possible candidates:
  bool Foo::operator!() const
```

in which case, change your documentation to

```
/// @fn Foo::operator!() const
/// @brief Some info about the operator
/// @return Some stuff about what the operator! returns
```

note the additional `() const` appended to the `@fn` identifier.

Comment: Also I didn't notice the warning in my doxygen output, because this file has like 1200 undocumented items. A complete API definition sits in there.

Comment: Turn off warnings for undocumented items. You should still get warnings such as the above because it's a different kind of error.